# Combining multiple OR statements in one - PHP

Tags: php, logic

I have an `IF` statement that consists of many `OR` conditions I want to ask if there is anyway I can reduce the `OR` conditions by combining them into one statement instead of the multiple conditions

```
if (($request->payment_method == "Bank_Transfer") || ($request->payment_method  == "Credit/Debit Card")
        || ($request->payment_method == "POS") ){

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like below:

```
if (in_array($request->payment_method, ["Bank_Transfer", "Credit/Debit Card", "POS"])) {

}
```